# What does plus equals(+=) operator means here?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I was working out sample code of Windows phone and often I see statements with `+=` operator.

I know about *add assignment operator* which does the below operation

```
+= means a = a + b;  // used for both adding number and string concatenation
```

But this is new to me

```
phNumChoseTask = new PhoneNumberChooserTask();
phNumChoseTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhoneNumberResult>(phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed);
```

Here how does `+=` works?

Comment: See [Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx)

Answer (score 24):

In the current context `+=` means `subscribe`. In other words it's like you are telling `subscribe my method (the right operand) to this event (the left operand)`, this way, when the  event is raised, your method will be called. Also, it is a good practice to `unsubscribe` (`-=` from this event, when you have finished your work ( but before you dispose you object ) in order to prevent your method being called and to prevent resource leaks. FMI look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

The += operator is used to specify a method that will be called in response to an event; such methods are called event handlers. The use of the += operator in this context is referred to as subscribing to an event.

Other usage, It can also be used as assignment operator:

```
a=a+b;
```

can be written as

```
 a+=b;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is creating a delegate (pointer) to **phoneNumberChooserTask_Completed**
and adding it to **Completed's** list of "Event Handlers".

The **-=** will remove an event handler from the event.

*Note*: Delegates perform the same way at events, so you can have multiple assignments to either a delegate or event, and when the delegate or event is executed, all assignments will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here it means that 'attaching (or lets say assigning) a new event handler' to phNumChoseTask. you can detach it also by '-=' programmatically.